# DAW fit for composing/recording in standard music notation?

Tags: open-source, music, music-production, music-composing, music-sheet

### Needed Software

Software, preferably Gratis/FOSS & Linux, that allows:

- The use of standard music notation to compose music in a variety of genres.
- The ability to play such compositions.
- Ideally the ability to transpose interactively "recorded" MIDI & Drum tracks to standard notation.
- The ability to print such notation as score sheets.
- The ability to do "regular recording" in the same tool (i.e., with microphones).
- Suitable for professional use.

### Background

I was curious about what's the best recording software for a classically trained musician, but one who writes indie rock/pop/folk/hip-hop/EDM?

In fact, I'm not professionally trained, but I grew up around some top-notch classically trained musicians, and I know how to read music, and I enjoy scoring my own music in Finale-like applications like MuseScore or Notion.

I'm still learning, but I can definitely sense myself steadily improving, and I am currently at a place in my life where I can pursue music as a profession, and I want to do some DIY projects to record my music (as well as work with experienced professional recording engineers).

So if I want to continue to grow in terms of standard music notation composition/transcription, but also make "modern" sounding music with drums and synths (often not recorded, but just input directly from the [computer] keyboard), how can I "kill two birds with one stone"?

I mean, I would be happy to focus on Garage Band, Fruity Loops, Audacity, Logic, etc. (though I prefer open-source/cheap software, and I prefer Linux, but not a deal-breaker if there's not Linux version), but I would like to choose a software package that is well-integrated with standard music notation.

I don't know if any of these packages that the average "producer" uses would satisfy my standard music notation requirement, but if you know of any, I would greatly appreciate some advice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. // Currently, this is a big wall of text. So please also format your post so that it becomes readable. Structuring it using paragraphs would already help a lot.

Comment: Agreed 100% There is probably an answerable question in there, but my head hurts from trying to read it (which probably explains the downvotes, none of which are mine)

Comment: I hope my edits make this question clearer  and capture the OPs intent.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest taking a look at [Denemo](http://denemo.org/) which seems to fit a lot of your requirements:

1. Music input from teh PC Keyboard, MIDI Controller or acoustically
2. Produces sheet music in various notations vial [LilyPond](http://lilypond.org) to produce beautifully typeset sheet music.
3. Your music can produce prints, images and music files as well routing your music in real time to other applications.
4. Import PDF files for transcribing from. Links can be placed in the music to points in the original.
5. Audio output as you work
6. Export as MIDI, OGG or WAV file, including live performance on MIDI keyboard.
7. Playback with an internal sampler in real time.
8. Route your midi or audio data to other applications (e.g. with JACK)
9. Support is there for creating the widest range of notation – Tablature, Chord Charts, Fret Diagrams, Drums, transposing instruments, ossia, ottava, cue, etc.
10. Linux, Windows (includes a portable edition) & Mac
11. Free, Gratis & Open Source
12. Graphical title pages, ornaments etc., using [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) *(which is also free, open source & cross platform)*

[image]